# how to merge by matching one to one in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes which are like this

```
DataFrame 1

item.ID       Name        Amount    Stock
A            Ball           10       12  
A            Ball           15       7
B            Basket         30       4

DataFrame 2

Item.ID      Name         Amount    Stock
A            Ball          10        10
A            Ball          15        7
C           Iron Box       100       2
```

As you can see when I merge using Item.ID it gives me duplicate entries. At the end there comes more than 4 `A` rows. I how can I match the item ID one to one basis, because I don't want to remove duplicates as you can see there are two A's in my df. so if I do one to one basis each A will surely get another A. I searched for such a solution but I didn't find one.

**Edit:**
Desired output on `.merge(on='Item.ID', how=outer, indicator=True)` is

```
item.ID    Name    Amount  Stock  item.ID   Name    Amount   Stock  _merge
A          Ball      10      12     A       Ball      10      10      both
A          Ball      15      7      A       Ball      15      7       both
B          Basket    30      4                                      left only
                                    C       IronBox   100     2     right_only
```

That I need just first `A` of df1 match with the first `A` of df2 and second `A` to match with second `A` of df2 (One to One matching, with duplicates). **please dont give answer as `on=['Item.id, 'Amount']` because all rows dont have Amount. Please give in `on='item.ID'` itself**

Thanks

Comment: what do you want your final dataframe to look like?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @hacker315 added

Comment: @MayankPorwal I have added the desired df.

Comment: If you want to match the first As you need some identifiers between them. Then you can use something like this: `.merge(on=['Item.ID','your_identifier'], how=outer, indicator=True`

Comment: @Hamid Oh I think I get it. but how can I add a column values like first duplicate has column value as 1, second duplicate has column value as 2 etc? is there any line that I can add to make duplicate count index...

Comment: Does the order of the items matter? That is - you'd like to match the first A on the right to the first A on the left, second A to second A, etc?

Comment: @Roy2012 no it doesnt matter.. but has to be one to one.. I dont want duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proposed solution. Add a running counter to each group, and then join on the running-counter and on the item ID:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["A", "A", "B"], 
                   "Name": ["Ball", "Ball", "Basket"], 
                   "Amount": [10, 15, 30], 
                   "Stock": [12, 7, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["A", "A", "C"], 
                   "Name": ["Ball", "Ball", "Iron Box"], 
                   "Amount": [10, 15, 100], 
                   "Stock": [10, 7, 2]})


df1["group_counter"] = df1.groupby("ID", ).cumcount()

df2["group_counter"] = df2.groupby("ID", ).cumcount()

pd.merge(df1, df2, how = "outer", on = ["ID", "group_counter"])
```

The result seems to be what you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: Yup this is what I was looking for. Thanks